# sudo startx and not able to log in anymore

Tags: login

I did `sudo startx` then lost the left side bar and wasn't able to do anything. Therfore I shut down my computer, started it and discovered I wasn't able to log to my session anymore... Have anyone an idea of what's going on and how to cope with?

Comment: See [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). **In future, don't run `startx` using `sudo`.**

Comment: Try `sudo rm .Xauthority` from the terminal (ctrl + alt + f1)

Comment: Perfect! Thqnks! I would not do it anymore!